# stationary distribution of a transition matrix

Tags: matrix, probability-or-statistics

How can I solve the stationary distribution of a finite Markov Chain? In other words, how can I estimate the eigenvectors of a transition matrix?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, whynot! Please let us know what you tried. In addition, may I suggest: 1) As you receive help, try to give it
too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [Read the FAQs](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [clicking 
the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Eigensystem[ ]` command would be the way to go. Say you have a transition matrix:

```
trans = Transpose[{{1/6, 1/6, 4/6}, {0, 3/4, 1/4}, {1/10, 1/10, 8/10}}]
```

Then you would get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors as:

```
{eVals, eVecs} = Eigensystem[trans]
```

You can interpret these using

```
eVals // MatrixForm
```

and

```
eVecs // MatrixForm
```

In this case, for the transition matrix above, the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$ is the first row of the eVecs matrix, which is $\{ 0.12, 0.48, 1.\}$. You can check that this is true by evaluating

```
trans.{0.12, 0.48, 1.}
```

which indeed returns $\{ 0.12, 0.48, 1.\}$. To get the actual steady state distribution, you would need to normalize this, i.e., divide the vector by the sum of the elements

```
{0.12, 0.48, 1.}/Total[{0.12, 0.48, 1.}]
```

Comment: nice answer! Another way to do the last step would be `Normalize[{0.12, 0.48, 1.}, Total]`.

Comment: yes, it works, thanks. why do you need to transpose?

Comment: As commonly defined, a stochastic matrix has row sum equal to $1$, and has a left eigenvector corresponding to the unit eigenvalue. Mathematica computes right eigenvectors by default. So what the above does is to calculate the right eigenvector of $A'$, which is the desired left eigenvector of $A$.