# Total Variation Distance of probability matrix

Tags: matrix, probability-or-statistics

How can I calculate the [Total Variation Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) of a transition Matrix? is there any built in function? I've searched all documentation and haven;t found anything.

** More information:

Let me try to explain it better. let's say we have a transition matrix ($P$), $4\times4$ that describes the probability of going from a, b, c and d to a, b, c or d in 1 step.

We can calculate the stationary distribution of $P$, and that's called $\pi$ in the following equation, and $P_{yx}$ is the probability of going from state $y$ to state $x$ (a,b,c,d):

$$\frac12\sum_x\left|P_{yx}^t-\pi(x)\right|$$

What I want to do is calculate the Total Variation Distance of $P$ from $\pi$ after $n$ steps and starting on a given state.

*** This is what I have so far:

```
M = {{0.3, 0, 0.5, 0.2}, {0, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3}, {0.3, 0.2, 0, 0.5}, {0.4, 0.1, 0, 0.5}} 

B = Transpose[M] 

N[B] // MatrixForm

{eVals, eVecs} = Eigensystem[B]


eVals // MatrixForm 

eVecs // MatrixForm

eigenvector = eVecs[[1]]

Print["Stationary Distribution"]; 

eigenvector/Total[eigenvector]

Print["M after 1 step"]; 

M2 = MatrixPower[M, 2]
```

Comment: And what would that be in the context of markov chains? I would wild-guess the maximum difference (`Max[mat1-mat2]`) between the probabilities of events in some time given some initial condition (`MatrixPower[Q, n].initialVector`) versus in the limit should there be any?

Comment: Have you tried writing your own function?

Comment: In the Wikipedia definition, there are two probability distributions P and Q, and the total variation is defined as a function of the two. In your question, what are P and Q?

Comment: Let's say that I have a transition matrix (n x n), called P, and that I calculate its stationary distribution, which is an eigenvector with an eigenvalue of 1 (1 x n), and let'sc all it Q. Those are the two inputs of the equation in Wikipedia.

Comment: Help me see what I'm missing. The eigenvector has the probabilities of being in a certain state. The matrix the probabilities of "going from one to the other". Those aren't the same events, you can't compare them. That's why the matrix has n^2 elements and the vector n

Comment: The Wikipedia article specifies that P and Q live in the same domain, that is, both are probability measures on the same domain. In your setup I think that means you have to look at corresponding rows since they give the probability of transitioning from the same state to other possible states. Informally, something like max(abs(rowP-rowQ)) seems to be what you would use.

Comment: Your edit is fine, but you still haven't shown what you've tried. Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I initially tried to find something builtin mathematica, but then started to do the calculation manually. I'm adding what I have to the questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terms in the total variation distance need to be probability distributions. Here's one way to do it: take any starting vector $m_0$ (with nonzero entries that sum to $1$). You can interpret $m_0$ as the initial distribution of the states. Then $m_1=m_0\cdot P$ is the distribution of the states after one time step, $m_2=m_0\cdot P\cdot P$ is the distribution of the states after two time steps, etc., where $P$ is the transition matrix of the Markov chain. Now you have several distributions and you can apply the total variation (as in the Wikipedia article). This would be

```
 Total[Abs[m0 - m1]]/2
```

for the distance from $m_0$ to $m_1$. This is really just the 1-norm, so a more concise expression would be

```
Norm[m0 - m1, 1]/2
```

You could also take the distance between any of these distributions and the stationary distribution, as was calculated in [stationary distribution of a transition matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11535/11544#11544)

Comment: Of course, `Norm[m0 - m1, 1]/2` is equivalent to `ManhattanDistance[m0, m1]/2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the stationary distribution by getting the first eigenvector. Or, if I'm mistaken with this, just use eigensystem and filter by the eigenvector 1.

```
pi[p_] := Normalize[First@Eigenvectors[p, 1], Norm[#, 1] &]


totVar[m1_, m2_] := Total@Abs[m1- m2]/2
```

So if `p` is your transition matrix, `m` the vector with initial states and `n` the time

```
totVarMarkov[p_, m_, n_] := totVar{[pi[p]}, {Flatten@m}.MatrixPower[p, n]]
```

(Code untested)

Comment: Another way: `totVar[m1_, m2_] := ManhattanDistance[m1, m2]/2`.